# Bump outdated React version code snippet

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets, react

The Stack Snippet React version is outdated to such an extent that using a CDN link has become mandatory.

---

Stack Snippets provide React `16.6.3` as highest version.

However;

- React `16.6` is a very old minor, `16.14.0` has been around since **October 14, 2020**
- React `17` has been released more than a year ago (**October 20, 2020**)
- React `18` has been released previous month (**March 29, 2022**)

---

Since most of the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-hooks) / [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breact.js%5D%20%22hooks%22) questions are about [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) we're kinda force to use a custom CDN link to create snippets.

---

As suggested in this [2 year old meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333434/improved-support-for-react-in-the-code-snippet-editor) about improving React support:

**Can the React version be bumped to include at least a Hooks supported version? (Minimal `16.8`)**

---

[image]

Comment: See also (MSO): [Update the version of Babel Standalone (and others) used by Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386096/update-the-version-of-babel-standalone-and-others-used-by-stack-snippets)

Comment: When you consider that CodeMirror, the editor that drives the snippet function, is _five years_ out of date, I doubt this will happen any time soon. It's become really buggy in FF.