# Can the Stack Overflow code snippet facility be updated with newer library options?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

In Stack Overflow, there's a useful facility for adding runnable code in HTML and JavaScript. There is a dropdown list on the left-hand side of the dialog which offers several third-party libraries. But the versions listed are pretty much all out-of-date.

For example, today I wanted to post some code which used [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js) 3, but the options stop at 2.x and Vue.js 3 has been around for a while now.

[image: Drop-down list]

Comment: Sadly, [such requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377739/bump-outdated-react-version-code-snippet) are just ignored. You can leave this around and get some rep, but judging by past requests, better not build any hopes.

Comment: What a coincidence: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424776/please-update-libraries-that-can-be-embedded-in-stack-snippets-like-jquery

Comment: **To close voters:** The Stack Snippets feature is *not* only on Stack Overflow; it is implemented on some other sites as well. This question should *not* be closed as specific to Stack Overflow only.